# How to draw diagrams on math.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I am asking this question here because I don't have enough reputation to ask it on meta.math.stackexchange.

How do I draw diagrams to answer questions on trigonometry and geometry. I mean something analogous to MathJax.

Comment: You can't. Use https://www.geogebra.org/geometry or draw and save in your app

Comment: There are several question in the "Related" list which you might want to look at, d2a, as they appear to be asking pretty much what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks y'all for the comments. I just wish there was something more integrated into the website instead of copying and pasting. I saw a trigonometric question I'd love to answer using diagrams thats why I was searching.